# ¿Cómo hago que funcione mi pirámide de asteriscos en python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo este código que hace que se imprima una pirámide en el shell de python:

```
lineas = int(raw_input('Numero de lineas:')) 
for numero_linea in range(lineas): 
     espacios = lineas - numero_linea - 1 
     asteriscos = 1 + numero_linea * 2
     print " " * espacios + "*" * asteriscos
```

Tengo que volver esto una función en un módulo, y luego utilizar esta función para imprimir la pirámide con un script principal, e intenté de la siguiente manera:

Este es mi módulo

```
 def Piramide (asteriscos, altura, espacio):
      for altura in range(asteriscos): 
      espacio = asteriscos - altura - 1 
      asteriscos = 1 + altura * 2
      return (asteriscos, altura, espacio)
```

y lo ejecuto en mi script principal de la siguiente manera:

```
 altura = 0
 espacio = 1 

 asteriscos = int(raw_input('Ingrese la altura de su piramide :'))


 modulo1asteriscos.Piramide(asteriscos, altura, espacio)

 print " " * espacio + "*" * asteriscos 

 print "Esta es su piramide"
```

Lo único que esto me imprime son los 20 asteriscos pero no los espacios ni la altura.

Estoy utilizando Python 2.7.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varios problemas con el código que relaciona, trataré de mencionarlos todos:

1. El código del módulo `modulo1asteriscos` está mal indentado. Python es un lenguaje supremamente estricto con esto. Normalmente un indentado de presionar la tecla tabulador es suficiente para cada línea, más un tabulador adicional por cada sentencia dentro de estructuras de control como el `for` que usa `Piramide`. Es decir, la indentación correcta es:

   ```
   def Piramide (asteriscos, altura, espacio):
       for altura in range(asteriscos): 
           espacio = asteriscos - altura - 1 
           asteriscos = 1 + altura * 2
       return (asteriscos, altura, espacio)
   ```

   A diferencia de otros lenguajes como C++ o Java donde el inicio y
   fin de estas estructuras está definido por corchetes de apertura y
   de cierre, Python confía en que el indentado es suficiente para
   definir qué instrucciones debe ejecutar en el for. Tal vez el
   copiar-pegar el código le eliminó a usted la indentación requerida.
2. El módulo `Piramide` en realidad no debería retornar la tripla `(asteriscos,altura,espacio)` ya que su única función en realidad es imprimir una pirámide con los argumentos que le proveen, luego con:

   ```
   def Piramide (asteriscos, altura, espacio):
       for altura in range(asteriscos): 
           espacio = asteriscos - altura - 1 
           asteriscos = 1 + altura * 2
       return
   ```

   es suficiente.
3. Ahora sí, el principal problema ocurre porque este método en realidad no está imprimiendo nada. Si revisa el código del script inicial, la instrucción que imprime cada línea de la pirámide está en este script y no en el módulo `modulo1asteriscos`. Luego, ocurre que después de pedir en el script inicial al usuario la cantidad de líneas, ejecuta el método Piramide en el módulo, retorna la tripla (sin hacer nada más) y y después ejecuta por única vez la instrucción `print " " * espacio + "*" * asteriscos`, por lo que sólo imprime por única vez esta línea con la cantidad de asteriscos igual al número ingresado por el usuario. Para solucionar esto, mueva esta línea a su módulo:

   ```
   def Piramide (asteriscos, altura, espacio):
       for altura in range(asteriscos): 
           espacio = asteriscos - altura - 1 
           asteriscos = 1 + altura * 2
           print " " * espacio + "*" * asteriscos 
       return
   ```
4. Una vez mencionado esto, diré que el código del módulo no imprime correctamente la pirámide. El primer código que relaciona en la pregunta, por el contrario, sí funciona bien. Si revisa, este código sólo necesita como parámetro el número de líneas de la pirámide que debe imprimir. La altura no es necesaria ya que esta dependerá de la cantidad de líneas que imprima (o dicho de otro modo, la altura es igual al número de líneas, por lo que el parámetro puede llamarse o bien altura o bien líneas, pero no ambos). El número de espacios tampoco es necesario pasarlo como parámetro porque este se calcula en cada iteración del ciclo `for` por lo tanto, su módulo Piramide sólo necesita un parámetro: `lineas`. Puede copiar-pegar su primer código y convertirlo en un módulo y funcionará:

   ```
   def Piramide(lineas):    
       for numero_linea in range(lineas): 
           espacios = lineas - numero_linea - 1 
           asteriscos = 1 + numero_linea * 2
           print " " * espacios + "*" * asteriscos
       return
   ```

   Por último, en el shell no olvide importar modulo1asteriscos para que Python sepa qué es `Piramide()` y de dónde viene.

   ```
   import modulo1asteriscos
   lineas = int(raw_input('Numero de lineas:')) 
   modulo1asteriscos.Piramide(lineas)
   ```